# How does one take a variable from a http file and push it to node.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

I'm trying to have a user enter a string into a http file and use javascript to push what they enter into server side node.js as a variable.

```
<input type="text" name="hashtag1" value="" placeholder="#hashtag" class="format"> 

<center><h2 class="submit"><button>Submit </button></h2></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an http file, I can only imagine that you mean html file. Do you have a node.js server running? If you do, post the code you have so far.

As far as getting information from a user to a server with JavaScript, there are a few different ways. One popular way is to use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to send an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call with the appropriate values.